# How to feed the data to the view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, mvvm

I've beein creating POCs for quite a while trying to simplify the examples on numerous blogs. Somehow, I fail to see what I'm missing.

I have this XAML structure and I've bound the text block's contents to the property *Alpha* in the view model.

```
<Window ... >
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel></local:ViewModel>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Grid>
    ...
    <DataGrid ...>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Alpha}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The view model is really simple and at the moment only consist of a single property.

```csharp
class ViewModel
{
  public String Alpha { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, we need to feed the data to the view model, somehow. So I've created a simple getter for fake values.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private static IEnumerable<String> GetFakes()
  {
    yield return "beep";
    yield return "boop";
  }
}
```

I haven't found any clear example of how to **feed** this data to the view model (alternatively how to make the view model **fetch** the data). Please note that the data to be displayed is static and will not change in the first place so I won't need any notificators (or will I?) since all the info is ready to go at the initialization already.

Answer (score 0):

YOu should have main view model, that holds the list of your child viewmodels.

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridRowViewModel> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainViewModel(){
        Items = new ObservableCollection<DataGridRowViewModel>{
            new DataGridRowViewModel("Beep"),
            new DataGridRowViewModel("Meep")
        };
    }
}

class DataGridRowViewModel
{
    public string Alpha {get;set;}

    public DataGridRowViewModel(string alpha){
        Alpha = alpha;
    }
}
```

In your datagrid, you should bind against `Items` property, see `ItemsSource`.

```
<Window ... >
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Grid>
    ...
    <DataGrid ... ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <-- This DataTemplate applies TO DataGridRowViewModel -->
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Alpha}"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Let's verify if I got that right. To apply that on my simplified example (since yours is clearly a part of a bigger creation), the view model class needs to have a method e.g. *LoadStuff()*. In that method we set the property *Alpha* of itself to... what exactly? I think this is the stuck-point for me. I can obtain an **array** of strings but I need somehow to convey that info to the view model. But that requires "cutting up" the array into individual pieces. Where does that connection occur in your example (form *T[]* to *T*, *T*, *T* etc.)?

Comment: @KonradViltersten; I've updated the answer. See if that makes more sense.